# Is Ask Ubuntu linked in the ubuntu.com website?

Tags: support, promote, hyperlinks, site-promotion

I found a lot of peoples that does not know Ask Ubuntu yet, so I start looking if this important resource is linked in the main ubuntu.com web site and I was unable to find it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In due course we'll have more links, I link it from unity.ubuntu.com currently to send people asking those questions here.